# Magento global accounts set, but newsletter per storename or storeview - multi-store

Tags: customer, multistore, customer-account, newsletter

Our situation in shorthand: Magento 1.9.x global accounts set, but newsletter per storename or storeview - in multi-store environment.

We have encountered some unexpected behavior. Suppose two scenario's:

1. Share Customer Accounts = set to global

*Advantage* = 1 customer account, no duplicates

*Disadvantage* = the customer cannot subscribe to a second email list of another storename or storeview. Not acceptable.

2. Share Customer Accounts = set to store

*Advantage* = we can store a customers email per website again (member of 1, not member of 2 and unsubscribed for 3 for example)

*Disadvantage* = we have many duplicate user accounts that are one and the same. But only now have two same accounts. This also causes problems when entering backend orders and not carefully watching which store the current order is for and which account is the exact one beloning to that store. Our current config - but not ideal.

**My question:** how can we overcome this problem? I think in short, we would want to: enable global accounts; and als manage e-mail newsletter subscribers on a storename or storeview level. Can this be done?

Help appreciated

[image]

[image]

Some resources/but either old or not complete

[Cannot subscribe email newsletter to second storeview: email already exists](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/cannot-subscribe-email-newsletter-to-second-storeview-email-already-exists)

http://www.hostknox.com/clients/knowledgebase/410/How-to-enable-and-disable-customer-account-sharing-in-a-multistore-in-Magento.html

Looks promising: http://astrio.net/blog/multi-store-magento-newsletter/

Answer (score 0):

Might be a solution. Not tested.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multistore-newsletter-subscription.html